# Convert Sum(x) Keep( Dense_Rank Last Order by y) from oracle to BigQuery and keep group by in query

Tags: oracle, google-bigquery

I got oracle query as below.

```
with table_a as(
select 1 as call_key, date '2021-06-01' as customer_contact, 1 as  status from dual union all
select 1 as call_key, date '2021-06-02' as customer_contact, 2 as  status from dual union all
select 1 as call_key, date '2021-06-03' as customer_contact, 3 as  status from dual union all
select 1 as call_key, date '2021-06-03' as customer_contact, 4 as  status from dual union all
select 2 as call_key, date '2021-06-01' as customer_contact, 1 as  status from dual union all
select 2 as call_key, date '2021-06-04' as customer_contact, 1 as  status from dual
)
select call_key, Sum(status) Keep(Dense_Rank Last Order by customer_contact) as sum_result
from table_a
group by call_key
;
```

Result is like this:
| call_key| sum_resul|
| --------|----------|
| 1       | 7        |
| 2       | 1        |

I need to convert oracle language to BigQuery, but BigQuery needs to have 'group by' in query.

I try to use array_agg as below, but I cannot get the same result as oracle. Please Help!

```
with calls as (
  select *
    from unnest([struct(1 as call_key, date '2021-06-01' as customer_contact, 1 as  status)
                ,struct(1 as call_key, date '2021-06-02' as customer_contact, 2 as  status)
                ,struct(1 as call_key, date '2021-06-03' as customer_contact, 3 as  status)
                ,struct(1 as call_key, date '2021-06-03' as customer_contact, 4 as  status)
                ,struct(2 as call_key, date '2021-06-01' as customer_contact, 1 as  status)
                ,struct(2 as call_key, date '2021-06-04' as customer_contact, 1 as  status)
                ])
)
select call_key
      ,array_agg(status order by customer_contact,status desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)] as status1

from calls
group by call_key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```
select call_key, sum(status) sum_result from (
  select * from calls where true
  qualify 1 = dense_rank() over(partition by call_key order by customer_contact desc) 
)
group by call_key
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: The output is correct. But because in my real scenario, the columns in the group by is dynamic. Is it possible not to add the call_key between select and from? 

select call_key
      ,do_something_in_here_but_cnnot_Include call_key
from calls
group by call_key

Comment: consider voting up the answer if it helped. this motivates us to answer your next questions :o)