# Convert Sum(x) Keep( Dense_Rank Last Order by y) from oracle to BigQuery with limitation factor

Tags: oracle, google-bigquery, dense-rank

I got an oracle query as below.

```
with table_a as(
select 1 as call_key, date '2021-06-01' as customer_contact, 1 as  status from dual union all
select 1 as call_key, date '2021-06-02' as customer_contact, 2 as  status from dual union all
select 1 as call_key, date '2021-06-03' as customer_contact, 3 as  status from dual union all
select 1 as call_key, date '2021-06-03' as customer_contact, 4 as  status from dual union all
select 2 as call_key, date '2021-06-01' as customer_contact, 1 as  status from dual union all
select 2 as call_key, date '2021-06-04' as customer_contact, 1 as  status from dual
)
select call_key, Sum(status) Keep(Dense_Rank Last Order by customer_contact) as sum_result
from table_a
group by call_key
;
```

The result is like this:
| call_key| sum_resul|
|:---- |:------:|
| 1| 7|
| 2| 1|

In my real scenario, the table or other fields are dynamic, the only information I get is the column that needs to sum and the column needs to order by. So in a real scenario, the oracle query may be like as below.

```
select  spce.col1,barc.col2

---- I try to resolve this sum() 
,Sum(cmp.col5) Keep(Dense_Rank Last Order by cmp.col4) as sum_result 

from 
(SELECT spce.col1, spce.col2, spce.*, ddn.col1, ddn.col2, ddn.col3, cmp.col1, cmp.col2 
FROM project_name.tableA spce 
JOIN project_name.tableB ddn ON spce.col1 = ddn.col1 
JOIN project_name.tableC barc ON spce.col2 = barc.col2 
JOIN project_name.tableD cmp ON (barc.col3 = cmp.col3 AND barc.col4 = cmp.col4) WHERE 1 = 1) a11
where   TRUE QUALIFY 1 = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY a11.col1 DESC)) a11
group by spce.col1,barc.col2
;
```

I try to use array_agg as below, but I cannot get the same result as an oracle.

```
with calls as (
  select *
    from unnest([struct(1 as call_key, date '2021-06-01' as customer_contact, 1 as  status)
                ,struct(1 as call_key, date '2021-06-02' as customer_contact, 2 as  status)
                ,struct(1 as call_key, date '2021-06-03' as customer_contact, 3 as  status)
                ,struct(1 as call_key, date '2021-06-03' as customer_contact, 4 as  status)
                ,struct(2 as call_key, date '2021-06-01' as customer_contact, 1 as  status)
                ,struct(2 as call_key, date '2021-06-04' as customer_contact, 1 as  status)
                ])
)
select call_key
      ,array_agg(status order by customer_contact,status desc limit 1)[ordinal(1)] as status1
from calls
group by call_key
```

I've asked the same question before, but my description wasn't clear enough, so I'm asking again, hope someone can help me, thanks!

The URL of the previous question is as follows:
[Convert Sum(x) Keep( Dense_Rank Last Order by y) from oracle to BigQuery and keep group by in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70594698/convert-sumx-keep-dense-rank-last-order-by-y-from-oracle-to-bigquery-and-kee/70598104#70598104)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my real scenario, the table or other fields are dynamic, the only information I get is the column that needs to sum and the column needs to order by

Try below. As you can see the only fields being referenced here are `customer_contact` and `status`. all the rest of fields considered to be part of `partition by` and `group by`

```
select any_value(rec).*, sum(status) sum_result from (
  select (select as struct * except(customer_contact, status) from unnest([c])) rec, status
  from calls c
  where true
  qualify 1 = dense_rank() over(partition by to_json_string(rec) order by customer_contact desc) 
) t
group by to_json_string(rec)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the answer is very close to my needs,
I added my real SQL, can you give me some feedback based on this situation? Thanks.